# case and cast statement in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to write case statement in Terdata If active = 'Yes' Then 1 elseif active = No Then 0 else NULL. I tried

```
case  
  when cast(M_ACTIVE as integer)= 'YES' then '1' 
  when  cast(M_ACTIVE as integer) = 'NO' then '0' else  'null'  end
```

I am getting error character string failed conversion to numeric value.

Comment: you are casting M_ACTIVE as integer and comparing it with a string "Yes" or "NO".. hence the error

Answer (score 1):

An `integer` can neither have the value `YES` nor `NO` - lose the cast:

```
case  
  when M_ACTIVE = 'YES' then 1
  when M_ACTIVE = 'NO' then 0
  else null
end
```

Comment: It still give me same error.character string failed conversion to numeric value

Answer (score 0):

```
case  
  when M_ACTIVE = 'YES' then '1'
  when M_ACTIVE = 'NO' then '0'
  else 'null'
end
```